# Eclipse Android directory empty (only folders left)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, project

I closed my Android project via Eclipse (100% sure I didn't delete anything) and all my source files are gone, like classes, project file, property file etc.

I can not open my Android project anymore.

The only thing that are left are the following folders:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

One week ago it was looking like this:

[image]

Comment: I really don't know - maybe some wrong preferences (on project close). I can tell you what you can do to recover your files. Right click on the project name and do a `Restore from local History`. This is not a real answer, but maybe it saves your ass.

Comment: @BobMalooga I already closed the project to re-import it, and that was not possible so I can't do your option :(

Comment: Have you check your Recycle Bin ?, is it the same project, not an older version ?, it seems like a bad luck ! I hate to say you this, but probably you just lost your files, that's why it's important to make backups or have version control.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I was able to debug that Android project on my device, wow...

Comment: Do you have files in your `src` folder ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales They are all gone :S

Comment: so, can you debug ? do have the .apk file in `/bin` ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales After I closed the project I am not able to open it anymore, so I can't debug it anymore (directory is not in the eclipse file explorer), I only got the app on my device... no apk file left.